# Getting error while ADFS SSO authentication using Fedlet using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

I want to implement SSO for ADFS 2.0 using Fedlet.

I am getting following error while Fedlet (SP) initiated Single Sign-On using HTTP POST binding

**XML can not be signed due to either empty or unknown signature certificate alias in extended metadata.**

I am using following part in the sp.xml file

```
<pre lang="HTML">
<SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <dsig:X509Data>
                <dsig:X509Certificate>
                    30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 86 8b 27 30 03 35 3a 07 3a 20 96 d6 ed f4 b3 17 92 a0 d0 78 21 90 72 e3 26 9e bf 79 25 ee 56 ae e6 5b 0d 84 21 02 18 9b d3 df 55 8c 31 b0 6c bd 60 d4 d9 6e 4b 16 f6 96 34 e2 df 97 7e 0a 43 be e7 cc a3 7a 9c b9 d5 5a a0 8d fa 19 62 c8 85 58 ca 39 a7 51 57 94 6a bd 83 b1 03 ec 40 d1 6a 83 ac 48 9b 22 3d 7c 47 eb 75 a7 e3 2f 10 26 aa 51 31 56 9a bf 98 df bc b5 b2 a0 61 31 8d 18 26 cc fd 07 65 1c 4a fc 0a 32 6e 19 44 43 63 d6 b3 80 de f0 f6 83 a1 14 89 df ad 46 7d 0e c0 a7 86 77 95 08 12 9c f6 19 17 85 e1 b6 25 b0 04 2c 48 e4 27 21 fb 8f 42 91 33 95 57 6e 7c 50 13 93 91 ac 59 f5 7a 31 9e 83 8e bd 6a fd 56 79 8e 84 80 e2 04 9e 1a 85 15 79 5b 60 92 1a ac 90 13 9b 66 f5 e6 f7 d0 2a 2c 7d 23 71 15 53 bf 9c 3e c4 5c 6a b6 60 15 a1 14 03 e5 06 22 45 d7 bb 57 53 17 17 02 03 01 00 01

                </dsig:X509Certificate>
                <dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <dsig:X509IssuerName>CN = ADFS Signing - site details.com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
                    <!--<dsig:X509SerialNumber>?a9 a3 d3 07 9d 1d 13 ba 79 7b 06 06 94 97 04 cc f6 fb 91 e3</dsig:X509SerialNumber>-->
                </dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
                <dsig:X509SubjectName>CN = ADFS Signing - site details.com</dsig:X509SubjectName>
            </dsig:X509Data>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
```

Is SSL is required for both Identity Provider(IdP) and Service provider(SP). We have active SSL certificate at Idp side but no active SSL at SP side. Is this problem is due to SSL certificate?

Comment: Here SP side SSL certificate also implemeted but giving same error can any one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes SP side certificate would be required. I did same with OpenAM and there it was required.

Comment: Thanks Nitin. Is that format included in the sp.xml is fine or any updates required?